# "Горилья" или "гориллья"?

Tags: орфография, удвоенные-буквы

Как правильно: *"горилья"* или *"гориллья"?* Я имею в виду притяжательное прилагательное к "горилле".

Comment: А не проще ли сказать, например, шерсть гориллы?

Comment: Да всё дело в том, что я это слово прочитал в электронной книжке. Оно там с двумя Л. Но поскольку там же было неправильное "неметено", это написание тоже может быть неправильным. Интересно, как правильно, если хочется именно так сказать (точнее, написать). Даже если самому и не захочется. Просто знать, как правильно именно в таком виде.

Comment: Не могу найти такого варианта нигде. Возможен вариант (с натяжкой) "гориллина". Но электронные книжки - дело печальное порой. Сама много читаю в электронке, натыкаюсь тут и там на оплошности.

Comment: Спасибо за мнение! Вполне возможно, что Вы правы и такого слова нет, но всё-таки подожду ещё чьих-то ещё комментариев или ответа. Кстати, "гориллина" у меня почему-то ассоциируется с конкретной гориллой, а не с любой, может, по ассоциации с именами.

Comment: @UnaNana, вы неправы. Слова-то в словарях нет, но образование тут идти должно явно по образцу *лисий* или *песий* (хвост),  Аналогично и *"горил(л)ья морда"*, никак не *"гориллина"*.

Answer (score 4):

Вероятно, наиболее близкое правило написания при словообразовании от корня с двумя согласными на конце предусмотрено для случая стыкования такого корня с последующим суффиксом. Затруднение в данном случае может быть связано с появлением последующего согласного; тем не менее, там тенденция - к *сохранению сдвоенных* согласных корня (*галлы - га**лль**ский*, *балл - пятиба**лль**ный*), за очень немногими исключениями (кристалл - кристальный и слова с суффиксом -к-: Алла - Алка).

*Розенталь Д. Э., Джанджакова Е. В., Кабанова Н. П.. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию,1998*

http://knigi.link/grafika-orfografiya-fonetika/dvoynyie-soglasnyie-korne-styike-pristavki-22041.html

Поскольку в нашем случае проблемы последующего согласного нет, в духе этой тенденции логично сохранить двойное л (**гориллья**).

**P.S.** В сети такая ссылка на словарь Ожегова:

ГОРИЛЛА — ГОРИЛЛА, ы, жен. Крупная человекообразная обезьяна, живущая в Центральной Африке. | прил. **гориллий, ья, ье**. Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949 1992

Comment: Спасибо, Александр! Мнения разошлись. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Слово, конечно, не словарное, поэтому оба варианта возможны.
Я бы предпочла одно Л, по аналогии с другими образованиями от слов, имеющих удвоенную согласную в конце основы. *Кристальный, Алин* (от Алла, хотя раньше рекомендовали именно Аллин). Правда, тут есть еще "металлический", но там удвоенное Л произносится четко. И вообще, думаю, перед мягким знаком удвоения согласного быть не должно.

Comment: Спасибо! Мне тоже естественней кажется с одной в этом случае. Хотя ни за что бы не подумал, что пишут "Алин" от "Аллы"!

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  *пишут "Алин" от "Аллы"* - я на всякий пожарный уточню. То, что у Лопатина такое предложение было - и с той же мотивировкой, что у меня (удвоенные согласные в конце основы не требуются, если не произносятся) - это точно. Но вот воплотилось ли оно в жизнь, даже засомневалась, не следила, чем там кончилось.

Comment: До того как Вы написали про "Аллу", для меня "Алин" был только от уменьшительного "Аля". А "Аллин" я не помню, чтобы произносил, но если произнёс бы, то обязательно удвоенно. А  вот "металлический" коротко. Только я не очень понял: Вы тоже? *"Удвоенное Л произносится четко",* то есть коротко?

Comment: Нет, именно как удвоенное.

Comment: Интересно, получается у нас с Вами "Аллин" и "металлический" наоборот. Странно.))