# «Шиншилья» или «шиншиллья»?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов, словообразование, прилагательные

«Шесть шиншильих правил».
Верно написание с одной «Л» в слове «шиншильих», хотя «шиншилла»?

Answer (score 2):

В толковом словаре русского языка:

[шиншилла](https://www.vedu.ru/expdic/39298/), -ы, ж. Животное из отряда грызунов с ценным мягким густым и длинным мехом. || *прилагательное **шиншилловый***, -ая, -ое. Семейство шиншилловых (сущ.).

[**шиншилловый**](https://www.vedu.ru/expdic/119772/) прилагательное
1) см. шиншилла, связанный с ним.
2) Свойственный шиншилле (1,2), характерный для нее.
3) Принадлежащий шиншилле.
4) Изготовленный, сшитый из шиншиллы.

Словарь многих выражений: [шиншилловый](https://all_words.academic.ru/106356/%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9); толковый словарь Ожегова: [шиншилловый](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/270178/%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9).

Прилагательное *шиншиловый* (одна **л**) встретилось только в двух местах (и то – в тексте самой статьи, не в заглавии; обоснования такой трансформации двух **л** в одну я не нашла):
в [словаре галлицизмов](https://gallicismes.academic.ru/42428/%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9) и в [словаре Ушакова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1092050/%D0%A8%D0%98%D0%9D%D0%A8%D0%98%D0%9B%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%AB%D0%99).

Других *словарных* прилагательных от "шиншилла" я не обнаружила.

Нечасто "в миру" встречается *шиншиллин*, ещё реже – *шиншиллий*.
Думаю, что и эти прилагательные, и редкостное *шиншильин* (встречается только с одной **л**) можно считать авторскими вариациями.

На нашем сайте есть подобный вопрос: ["Горилья" или "гориллья"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427461/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F)

Comment: Если Вы не признаете краткое прил. *шиншиллов*, то как напишете "шиншилл.... правило", "шиншилл.... хвост"?

Comment: Я признаю краткое прилагательное: шиншиллов хвост; шиншиллова морда; шиншиллово единоборство; шиншилловы правила. Но при склонении все равно будет - *шиншилловых правил*. Вот тут тоже есть: https://kartaslov.ru/просклонять-прилагательное/шиншилловый. По словарям я находила _правильное_ прилагательное.

Comment: Теперь согласен

Comment: А-а! Вы решили, что я посчитала "шиншиллов" неверным! Возможно, я не совсем понятно выразилась в конце. Вы считаете, что необходимо поправить - для ясности?

Comment: Да, желательно.

Answer (score -1):

По-моему, правильно **шиншиллины** либо **шиншилловы**.

[Виктория Дергачёва. «Шиншиллин год». Пьеса](https://klauzura.ru/2012/08/viktoriya-dergachyova-shinshillin-god-pesa/)

[Словоформы слова "шиншиллов"](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: Думаю, что первого из этих слов не существует, а второе должно писаться с двумя "лл".

Comment: @grizzly Конечно, с двумя, так была описка. Но почему ссылка на пьесу не убеждает?

Comment: Не убеждает, потому что я не знаю, кто такая Дергачёва. А в словаре этого слова нет. Если бы Вы дали хотя бы ссылку на бумажное издание, в котором можно было найти фамилии корректора и редактора, я бы понял. Вы читали эту "пьесу"? Я прочитал треть страницы и "пополнил" свой словарный запас ещё одним словом "нечёделать". (Минус уберу и комментарии эти поудаляю, если согласитесь отредактировать ответ.)