# Как пишутся притяжательные прилагательные, образованные от имен Элла, Алла?

Tags: ономастика, прилагательные

Как пишутся притяжательные прилагательные, образованные от имен Элла, Алла?Смущает удвоенная *л*.

Примечание 1. Не путать с Аля -> Алин.
Примечание 2. Полезная информация:
["Горилья" или "гориллья"?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427461/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F)

Comment: Пример из Нацкорпуса: В ту самую пору, когда я еще был вхож в Иннин дом, где меня как будто бы охотно терпели, существовал у меня дружок, самый закадычный ― Федя. [А. И. Куприн. Инна (1928)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эллин пенал, Эллино платье, Эллина сумка.

Аллин платок, Аллино хобби, Аллина причёска.

Думаю, что такие прилагательные вполне приемлемы; пишутся с удвоенными согласными.

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

Ведь из верхней комнаты Анны, куда нужно подниматься по приставной лестнице, то и дело доносится счастливый Аннин смех и звучат менуэты! [Они принадлежат солнцу и вечности (2003) // «Театральная жизнь», 2003.05.26]

Comment: А Лопатин разве их не усек до одинарной согласной?!  Источник найду позже, если надо.

Comment: Не совсем так, усечение коснулось имён с суфф. -к-, например, Алка (Свод 2000: Следует писать одну согласную букву перед суффиксом -к(а) в уменьшительных и фамильярных формах личных имен типа Алка (от Алла), Эмка (от Эмма), Кирилка, Филипка (от Кирилл, Филипп) и